# See if a user is admin with hasPermission and mentions

Tags: javascript, node.js, embed, discord.js

I've been trying to make a Discord Bot recently and I've been stuck on this part for a while. I'm basically trying to make an Embed that sends a profile of the player that was pinged with different information like his name/ID/in which voice channel he is, etc. The thing is, I can't figure out how to make the "isAdmin" var I created recognized.

With `console.log()` I narrowed my problem down to 1 part; the `message.mentions.members.first()` isn't being defined but not read and it just skips the command like it was never typed. Here's my source :

```
case "profile":
    var isAdmin = "undefined";
    let profileMentionned = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!profileMentionned) return message.channel.send("some error message")
    if (profileMentionned.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
    {
        return isAdmin = "Admin boi";
    }else{
        return isAdmin = "Member pleb";
    }
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    Embed values....
```

Thank you for answering <3 :)

Comment: But does it send the message `some error message`?

Comment: No, this "error message" is for the members when they don't @someone, it's part of the bot

Comment: So where/what is the error that you get on console? Or what exactly doesn't work as expected?

Comment: When using that source and typing the command, it doesn't do anything and there's no console output. When I try putting `profileMentionned.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")` instead, it outputs "`Cannot read properly 'hasPermission' of undefined`" like it can't locate the mention in the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just noticed:

```
if (profileMentionned.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
{
    return isAdmin = "Admin boi";
//  ^^^^^^  
} else {
    return isAdmin = "Member pleb";
//  ^^^^^^  
}
```

You can't have the return on that if, because it will just stop doing the rest.
Instead just do `isAdmin = "Admin boi";`, so something like this would work:

```
var isAdmin = "undefined";
let profileMentionned = message.mentions.members.first();
if (!profileMentionned) return message.channel.send("some error message")
if (profileMentionned.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
    isAdmin = "Admin boi";
} else {
    isAdmin = "Member pleb";
}
var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
//...
```